# qnetworkaccessmanager QNetworkReply - race condition?

Tags: qt, network-programming, qt5

I have this QT-related question. QNetworkAccessManager::get() returns QNetworkReply pointer.  I can then connect to its finish slot:

```
QNetworkReply* r = nam->get(url);
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(_finishedThisReply()));
```

This seems the right way to do things, in particular, with this approach you can have simultaneous requests with the same QNetworkAccessManager object.  However, don't we have a race condition here?  What if between finishing get and calling connect the finished signal has been sent?  Or does QT guarantee that this will not happen?  I couldn't find anything about it in QT documentation yet.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have full control over what happens in the thread you run in, there can be no race conditions since your code is running here.

Of course, it's possible that the network access manager's internals are running in another thread. Suppose the following happened in the `QNetworkManager`'s implementation:

```
Thread A: QNetworkReply* r = nam->get(url);
Thread B: emit r->finished();
Thread A: connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()), ...);
```

That would be a problem indeed. Alas, the implementation can do something else:

```
Thread A: QNetworkReply* r = nam->get(url);
Thread B: QMetaObject::invokeMethod(r, "finished");
          // equivalent to QCoreApplication::postEvent(r, new QMetaCallEvent(...))
Thread A: connect(r, SIGNAL(finished()), ...);
          ...
```

Here a *signal* is emitted *synchronously*, within the reply's thread. This is in contrast to the first variant, where a signal was emitted asynchronously.

Eventually, thread A's control returns to the event loop, and the cross-thread method invocation, in the form of a `QMetaCallEvent`, is sent to `r`, emitting the signal.

I'm simplifying, but the semantics of `QNetworkReply` are those of the second, correct, variant. It "just works". There are no races, even if the network access manager's implementation was running in a separate thread.

Comment: I think QNetworkAccessManager does use extra threads in order not to block the main GUI thread. If I understand you correctly, you are saying, that QNetworkAccessManager will need to post the finished() event onto the main thread, and until this request has been processed in the main event loop I am safe to subscribe to the signal?

Comment: @Andre Yes, with the critical distinction between posting a slot call vs. posting a signal call. The call being posted is a signal, and it will get picked up by your thread once you return control to the event loop. If the net. mgr. posted a slot call (or *emitted* a signal), then your slot would not get called since at the time of signal's emission your slot wasn't connected yet. That latter scenario is the race you worried about.

Comment: Ok, to be clear, signal emission (sending it to currently connected slots) must be done via the main thread in the event loop, correct?

Comment: Yes. If the emission happens in the other thread, then you're subject to a race.

Comment: Well, do you know if QNetworkReply issues it on another thread?